react native modal while the keyboard is getting opening,the background page is getting visible.How to fix this?
Currently,am using react native modal while the keyboard is getting opening,the background page is getting visible.I have tried with keyboardAwareScrollView and aslo keyboardAvoidingView.How to fix this issue?any suggestions?
I need the background page should not be visible while opening the keyboard
